# Vagrant networking with company network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vagrant

I've got a VM running with Vagrant, but I'm unable to access our company's GitHub Enterprise domain (or any other internal domain within our company network) from within the VM.

I'm able to access our company's GitHub Enterprise domain from my host machine, but not from my guest VM.

Is there any additional configuration that I'm missing in my Vagrantfile below?

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1604"
  config.vm.box_version = "= 1.9.12"

  config.vm.define "docker" do |docker|
    docker.vm.hostname = "docker"
    docker.vm.provision "docker" 
    docker.vm.provision "file", 
      source: "provisioning/flask_app/", 
      destination: "/home/vagrant/"
    docker.vm.provision "file", 
      source: "provisioning/flask_nginx/", 
      destination: "/home/vagrant/"
    docker.vm.provision :shell, 
      privileged: false, 
      path: "provisioning/docker_provision.sh"
    docker.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.28.33.10"
    docker.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.cpus = 1
      vb.memory = 1024
    end
  end

end
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you ping or access any resources from the VM?  If not, you should check with your network/sys admin/team. Your internal switches could be configured for one MAC per port, or have other security restrictions that are preventing the VM from connecting to the network.